# Creating Arrays from cvs files in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv

So I have a data file, which i must extract specific data from. Using;

```
x=15 #need a way for code to assess how many lines to skip from given data
maxcol=2000 #need a way to find final row in data
data=numpy.genfromtxt('data.dat.csv',skip_header=x,delimiter=',')
column_one=data[0;max,0]
column_two=data[0:max,1]
```

this gives me an array for the specific case where there are (x=)15 lines of metadata above the required data and where the number of rows of data is (maxcol=)2000. In what way do I go about changing the code to satisfy any value for x and maxcol?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas`.  Its `read_csv` function does all that you want (I don't include its equivalent of `delimiter`, `sep=','`, because comma-delimited is the default):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.dat.csv', skiprows=x, nrows=maxcol)
```

If you really want that as a numpy array, you can do this:

```
data = data.values
```

But you can probably just leave it as a pandas `DataFrame`.

Comment: Thankyou, what exactly does the panda module do. How does the read_csv function differentiate between lines? I don't want to use unfamiliar functions that could trip me up. Also what would the long hand way be? Ie not using an extra module to do the work for me?

Comment: Pandas is a package designed for working with structured data (like `csv` files).  It differentiates between lines the same way `genfromtxt` does, using line breaks (by default, although you can specify this).  It is really designed for handling `csv` files in a reliable and robust way., you are much less likely to run into problems and corner cases compared to `genfromtxt`.

Comment: It seems like it would do all the heavy lifting for me, however my aim is to use no outside packages, so for now it seems I am stuck with genfromtxt. In what direction would you suggest heading to get the most flexible code from genfromtxt?